# Accessing Citrix Powershell SDK (or other 3rd party ps SDK) from C# .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, sdk, citrix

So Citrix left out their old .NET SDK framework such as the RunSpaceFactory and MFCOM in favor of a PowerShell SDK in 7.x.

I understand that powershell commands can be run using C# and other .NET languages.  The problem is, despite this PowerShell SDK being installed on this computer where I am using Visual Studio, I can't gain access to the commands as System.Management.Automation does not have these commands in the library. The commands are in some other library installed with the PowerShell SDK.

I can use them from the command prompt but that's about it.

How do I access these commands from .NET?

Answer (score 0):

hello I used powershell in xenapp 6.5 and works only if you install the SDK and executed powershell on datacollector, therefore did not think that it works on VisualStudio without xenapp installed on the local machines.

Comment: XenApp 6.5 is great, it worked well, this is 7.6 though and they really messed up with this. I can't access the powershell commands. I installed Studio on the dev box and it's got the powershell sdk installed, but VS does not let me talk to that, it just ends up telling me that command does not exist.